# using Gadfly with a conda-installed julia

Tags: anaconda, julia, conda, miniconda

For a future use in a jupyter context, I want to try julia through a conda installation. To do so I did the following:

```
conda create -n test_julia
conda activate test_julia
conda install -c conda-forge julia
```

From there I can start julia. However when trying, for instance, the gadfly module for doing basic test plots, I get the following error:

```
julia>using Pkg
julia>Pkg.add("Gadfly")
julia>using Gadfly


Error: Error building `Arpack`: 
│ [ Info: Downloading https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/ArpackBuilder/releases/download/v3.5.0-3/Arpack.v3.5.0-3.x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc7.tar.gz to /home/pellegrini/.julia/packages/Arpack/UiiMc/deps/usr/downloads/Arpack.v3.5.0-3.x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc7.tar.gz...
│ ERROR: LoadError: LibraryProduct(nothing, ["libarpack"], :libarpack, "Prefix(/home/pellegrini/.julia/packages/Arpack/UiiMc/deps/usr)") is not satisfied, cannot generate deps.jl!
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
│  [2] #write_deps_file#152(::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::Array{LibraryProduct,1}) at /home/pellegrini/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/4F5Hq/src/Products.jl:414
│  [3] (::getfield(BinaryProvider, Symbol("#kw##write_deps_file")))(::NamedTuple{(:verbose,),Tuple{Bool}}, ::typeof(write_deps_file), ::String, ::Array{LibraryProduct,1}) at ./none:0
│  [4] top-level scope at none:0
│  [5] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [6] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
│  [7] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [8] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
│  [9] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at /home/pellegrini/.julia/packages/Arpack/UiiMc/deps/build.jl:74
```

I read that this problem could be due to the use of a julia built from source.
I suppose that it is not the case when using a conda installation. Being a bit new to conda and julia, I can't find why I have this error and how to solve it. Would you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Install Julia via the Julia installer and make a link Julia=>Conda rather than Conda=>Julia.
Currently all major Julia=>Conda integration issues seem to be solved and work seamlessly. This is also a standard way to work Python-Julia so this scenario will also get updates more quickly.

Since you you probably want to glue Julia to your existing Anaconda installation (rather than install a private Anaconda for your Julia which is the default option) you need to set PYTHON environment variable (this can be done in shell or with the following Julia commands):

```
#Windows:
julia> ENV["PYTHON"]="C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"
#Linux
julia> ENV["PYTHON"]="~/anaconda3/bin/python"
```

Now you can press `]` for the package manager and this is what you usually want to execute:

```
(v1.0) pkg> add PyCall Conda PyPlot
```

Now you will have integration with the external Anaconda. 
Looking at your question this is the best scenario.

Comment: thx for the info. Unfortunately still having troubles. 1- I picked up a prebuilt julia. 2- From there, I declared `PYTHON` envvar in my shell. 3- I run Julia and tried to add Gadfly. 4- I get the following error: ERROR: LoadError: No deps.jl file could be found. Please try running Pkg.build("Arpack").
Currently, the build command might fail when Julia has been built from source
and the recommendation is to use the official binaries from julialang.org.

Comment: ok that works now. Just tried to do what was written (i.e. building Arpack) ... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it might be [this known issue](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl/issues/5). Based on the discussion of this issue I fixed it on my machine by installing `openblas` and adding this link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libopenblas.so /usr/lib/libopenblas64_.so.0
```

(Note that I'm not using conda, I was using the standard Arch package.)